# How to assign a hotkey to an unlisted menu item in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys

I need to use an Eclipse plugin which requires a menu button be clicked every time we want to execute code. This menu button does *not* appear under **Preferences -> General -> Keys**.

The menu:

[image: menu]

The only related Keys I found:

[image]

Menu Spy:

[image]

**Is there a way to hotkey/macro run the process?**